# How to turn on/off the AllowAdditions property on a subform

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create a button on a subform (frmeffortimpact) embedded in a main form (frmProjectCharter01).  Simply, I would like the button to turn on and off the AllowAdditions property.  Unfortunately I am getting syntax error messages with the below code:

```
Private Sub cmdAddImpacts_Click()


If Me.Forms("frmProjectCharter01").Forms("frmeffortimpact").AllowAdditions = True Then

    Me![frmEffortImpact].Form.AllowAdditions = False
    Me.Immagine52 = True
    Me.Immagine55 = False


ElseIf Me.Forms("frmProjectCharter01").Form("frmeffortimpact").AllowAdditions = False Then

    Me![frmEffortImpact].Form.AllowAdditions = True
    Me.Immagine52 = False
    Me.Immagine55 = True

End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

I was overcomplicating it. Here is the answer to my question:

```
Private Sub cmdAddImpacts_Click()

  If Me.AllowAdditions = True Then

      Me.AllowAdditions = False
      Me.Immagine52.Visible = True
      Me.Immagine55.Visible = False

  ElseIf Me.AllowAdditions = False Then

      Me.AllowAdditions = True
      Me.Immagine52.Visible = False
      Me.Immagine55.Visible = True

  End If


End Sub
```

Comment: You will want to press "Accept" for this answer, I think.

Comment: You have to wait two days prior to being able to accept your own answer